# many input form submission very slow alternativ progress bar loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form who take like 2 minutes to submit there is like 350 input , its normal it take so long ? what kind of alternative i have ? maybe put a progress bar / loader in javascript when i click on submit button?

```
<form method="post" class="std" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr class="highlighted odd selected-line">
        <td class="text-right">
            <input name="attributes[]" value="Genre : Femme, Taille : S, Couleur : Gris, Modele : Debardeur" type="hidden">
            <input name="combination_reference[]" value="MARKET-FEMME-DEBARDEUR-GRIS-S" type="hidden">
            <input name="combination_price[]" value="30.00" type="hidden">
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: Please could you post your entire code, not just a little portion, thanks. It is useful to see the entire form. Also, please post the code of what handles the form (where is is posted to, is it with ajax, php etc).

Comment: How can i post all the form it got like 3000 line

Comment: Are they *all* hidden fields? Or just a few of the 350?

Comment: Well, I will assume that most of them are fields that people fill out. If that is the case, you could break the form down into multiple forms, so that each individual form takes much less time and it seems faster. Like filling out an application. However, although 350 `input`s is quite a few, that's probably only a few KB of data. I would look at how long the request takes versus the response, it might be that your big problem is really that it takes minutes to make dozens of DB queries and add/update data, you might need to focus on that part.